¿Cómo hacer un subset de un dataframe en el condicional sea que los elementos de una variable no estén incluidos en los elementos de otro vector?
Tengo un dataframe en el que hay una variable que contiene el nombre de diferentes especies. Quiero hacer un subset de ese dataframe en el que NO estén las observaciones en las que el nombre de la especie coincida con las de alguna de mi vector.
De momento he conseguido que me devuelva un dataframe con las que SÍ están en el vector con lo siguiente:
dataDefC<-dataC[dataC$Assigned %in% listaDelC,]

, pero necesito uno con las que NO.

Podés darle un vistazo a la función setdiff, hace exactamente lo que buscas.

¿Como funciona un comparación de este estilo:  mtcars$cyl %in% c(1,3,4)? Simplemente evalua cada valor del vector de la izquierda y asigna un verdadero o falso segun se cumpla o no la comparción.
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

Si bien no existe un "not in" especifico, la negación de este vector, es la condición inversa es decir el "not in":
!(mtcars$cyl %in% c(1,3,4))
    
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[25]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

En tu caso, sería hacer:
dataDefC<-dataC[ !(dataC$Assigned %in% listaDelC), ]


Solucionado. Muchas gracias por la info.

@Fran Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si es que así lo consideras. Saludos
